# Is there a command to add a project reference?

Tags: visual-studio, powershell

I'm loving the copy paste of a nuget package id from another packages.config into the command line with `install-package` on it, was hoping to do the same with project references.

Is there an already existing command or shortcut to add a project reference instead of nuget package install reference from the package manage console (powershell console) in Visual Studio?

Answer (score 0):

The [Visual Studio Productivity Power Tools 2012](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/3a96a4dc-ba9c-4589-92c5-640e07332afd) include the latest version of the [Power Commands](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/e5f41ad9-4edc-4912-bca3-91147db95b99) (this links to the VS2010 version). With that you can rightclick a (set of) reference(s) and copy them. Then paste them to another project. It's not exactly what you're after I think, but it is pretty close :).